# execution of files from shell execlp

Tags: c, unix, process, fork

I have an exercise that asks me to complement the code , so that his execution obtained as a result equivalent to `$ date> out.txt`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NEWFILE (O_WRONLY | O_CREAT)
#define MODE644 (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)

int main() {
    int fd;
    if (fork() == 0) {
        //// Code Here for add/// Result

        fd=open("out.txt",NEWFILE,MODE644);
        dup2(fd,1);
        close(fd);

        execlp("date",NULL);
        exit(0);
     }
     wait(NULL);
 }
```

I can not understand the three lines that have been added:

```
 fd=open("out.txt",NEWFILE,MODE644);
 dup2(fd,1);
 close(fd);
```

Answer (score 0):

The tricky bit is `dup2`.

```
int dup2(int fildes, int fildes2);
```

It closes `filedes2` and makes it a clone of `filedes`. Which means, from now on when you refer to `filedes2` it's as if you referred to `filedes`. Back to your code, you should know that `STDOUT_FILENO` is `1`.

So your code means:

- Open a file (descriptor `filedes`)
- Close `STDOUT_FILENO` and make it refer to `filedes`

Answer (score 0):

`open` opens the file and returns a file descriptor. [`dup2(fildes, fildes2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html) "shall cause the file descriptor fildes2 to refer to the same open file description as the file descriptor fildes", i.e. it closes standard output (if it's open) and makes stdout a copy of your new file descriptor. `close` then closes `fd` as it's no longer needed, since stdout is now the file you just opened.